# Why won't my application connect to SQL Server database when I can connect using SQL Server Management Studio with the same login?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I realize this may be a difficult (impossible?) question to answer since I can't provide access to the actual server involved, but maybe there's something obvious I'm missing.

I have a C# Windows Forms application (.Net 4.5) that needs to connect to a SQL Server 2012 database. The connection string in `App.config` is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnStr"
    connectionString="server=SERVERNAME.ads.lcl;database=MyDatabase;uid=MyUser;password=abcdefg1234567"
    providerName="AspNetSqlProvider" />
```

I am able to connect to and read from the database with SQL Server Management Studio using the same login and password (with SQL Server Authentication), so I know I have the server, database, uid, and password correctly specified in the connection string. But when I debug my program, I get an SQLException saying `Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MyUser'.`

I've done this a thousand times before, so I'm at a loss.

Here are the relevant sections of code, if it helps at all:

```
public static string MyConnStr
{
  get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnStr"].ConnectionString; }
}

public static int[] GetIntArrayFromDB(string query)
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyConnStr))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
      using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
      {
        try
        {
          conn.Open();
          da.Fill(dt);
          conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
          return null;
        }
        finally
        {
          if (conn != null)
            conn.Dispose();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  int numRows = dt.Rows.Count;
  int[] retInt = new int[numRows];
  for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
  {
    retInt[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]);
  }

  return retInt;
}
```

The query being passed to `GetIntArrayFromDB()` is `"SELECT myID FROM myTable"`. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: The approach above with the named connection string is perfectly valid and works, if you don't misspell the connection string name in the config file. Sorry for this, I'm working on a sleep deficit. Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions!

Comment: Have you checked the SQ Server error logs?

Comment: Do you need to specify the initial catalog in your connection string? I.e. the name of the database on the database server.

Comment: Do you have enabled the TCP protocol in the Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: A Web Application project *in the same solution* is using the exact same connection string format with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the connection string specified in the `App.config` file to the following (note that the format of the connection string itself is the same, only the name is different):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="server=MyServer.ads.lcl;database=MyDatabase;uid=MyUser;password=abcdefg1234567"
    providerName="AspNetSqlProvider" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and by referencing the connection string in my C# code this way:

```
get
{
  return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
}
```

I do **NOT** understand why this made any difference! It seems quite bizarre.

Comment: In the other application, (that *works*, with the original connection string), how are you referencing the connection string in that C# code?  Also, what inspired the line `<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />` ?

Comment: With `ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;` - looking at the other application is where I got the idea to change it. But I've used the reference by name before with no problems.

Comment: Quite intresting ... what is the contents of `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` when using old(not-working) approach? Can you print it out please?

Comment: @aleksey.berezan It's in the second indented block, of the original question ("relevant sections of code"):  `get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnStr"].ConnectionString;`... which is why he commented, immediately above, "But I've used the reference by name before with no problems."

Comment: OK, I now have egg on my face. I changed it back to the other approach and it worked this time! I must have had a typo in the connection string name in `App.config` (the "real" connection string name was not actually `MyConnStr`).

Comment: What an honest guy, admitting that :)  You might want to append that to the bottom of either your answer, or your question, as an `UPDATE:`

Comment: I just did - at least someone might get something out of the question and the comments, since some of you did say you haven't used my connection string format, the named connection string reference, etc. before.

Comment: @Doug_Ivison, that was not what I meant, but anyway, problem's solved, so never mind :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server, then your connection string should be something like the following

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
 connectionString="Data Source=DatabaseServer; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; User ID=UserName; Password=YourPassword;"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Not sure if your example just isn't using the "Data Source" and "Initial Catalog" entries, but it looks like you're using "server" and "database" instead.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I can't use Windows Authentication in this case.

Comment: @timbck2 For possible readers, I deleted my comment above re' Windows Authentication, so I could repost it here with a correction to something confusing I said in it:  Just so you know some options, an alternative to SQL Server Authentication (`;uid=MyUser;password=abcdefg1234567`) is to use Windows Authentication (`;integrated security=SSPI`)

Answer (score 0):

According to [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/), your connection string should be in this format for SQL 2012:

> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
>   Password=myPassword;

I've never used the format you are using, give this a shot.

Comment: The connection string format I'm using has always worked for me before, and in fact it works in a Web Application project *in the same solution* as this Windows Forms project.

Comment: You are saying two projects in the same solution using the same connection string exhibit different behavior? Or just the same connection string format?

Comment: The same connection string exactly. Copied and pasted.